# Spring PostMapping return 401 without body

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I want to make a `Post` to write some data into the database, but all needed information is stored on the server, so my `Post` service requires no body:

```
@PostMapping("foo")
public @ResponseBody 
RestResponse writeFoo() {
    // WRITE AND RETURN
}
```

If I try to make a post request to this service I receive 401 even if I pass a valid token. If I change my exposed service to a `GetMapping` all works as expected. It seems that I can't manage a `Post` request with an empty body.

I've tried adding some fake parameters as

```
RestResponse writeFoo(@RequestBody(required = false) String fake)
```

but without success.

Any idea?

Comment: 401 status - Unauthorized. Check your security configuration, or disable for test.

Comment: if i use a get all works well. i have already various post services and all works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you explain is most commonly the cause of bad (or missing?) configuration.

Pay attention that i.e. GET method is allowed by default by your REST API, while you need to specify other method types (i.e. PUT and POST), otherwise it won't work out of the box due to CORS.

The part where GET method works while POST method doesn't is a strong hint towards missing/incorrect CORS configuration. You can fix it quickly by adding some CORS filter and setup your response headers.

The official documentation should give you a good start, if you don't know where to look for: [Spring docs - enabling CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

**UPDATE:**

The issue is successfully resolved, check comments section for more info.
Short story - back-end configuration for CORS/CSRF token was set up correctly in this particular case, **the issue occurred due to missing header (CSRF token) on the angular/front-end part of the webapp.**

Comment: thanks for your response, but I think I have CORS well configured. This problem is present also if I call service from postman

Comment: Please start your webapp in debug mode and place breakpoint to see if you even get to this endpoint/method when you set it the request method to POST. If you can't, then it's a strong signal that your filters/config don't allow you to issue any POST request.

Comment: nope. it can't be the problem. I already use some post requests in this application and they all works correctly

Comment: Change log level of Security and you can see who and why was decline you request. Add to the properties: logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Comment: That's interesting, given that you said the POST request didn't work either without body OR with some dummy data in the request payload (request body). My only suggestion was to check out whether it's something related to CORS, given that GetMapping works.... i.e  if some header or CSRF token is missing. Also check out the request and response in network headers of your browser or in postman that you use, along with your logs

Comment: thanks man, the problem was the CSRF that i forget to import into angular 6. I'm migrating my frontend project and i forget about that. borino update your answer with logging property and I'll accept your answer